# Spring jar files

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, jar

Do Spring jar files cost money now ?
The link is taking me to JFrog and it asking to login
they have pricing for that

Thanks

I am trying to get or download Spring jar files for spring use; does anyone know how to download Spring jar files and install them to Intellij

Comment: No they don't cost money, JFrog costs money. The repositories have changed (and this has been communicated a long time ago), you should now use maven central to get the jars not the jfrog one anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked it was possible to download them from
https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/release/org/springframework/

But from what I see that is no longer available, so your safest bet is to simply create a maven project, add dependencies that you want

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

And go on your machine to a folder

```
C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.0.9
```

or

```
C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.0.9
```

This is a workaround that I heard many people use if they are not allowed to use Maven for their projects.